# Method statement not working on production server, does on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

When AJAX is calling my laravel method, the method is called, but the var for the search term is null (Using Select2 for my combobox). However, the same code runs fine on my local dev machine.

I've updated laravel to 5.8.11 to see if that would help as my local machine was running a slightly newer build, php, reviewed logs, chrome inspector, nothing shows any errors for this.

```php
   public function get_codes(Request $request)
    {
        $search = trim($request->q);

        if(empty($search))
        {
            return response()->json([]);
        }     

        $data = [];
        $data = DB::table("codes")
                ->select("id","dx_code", "description")
                ->where('dx_code','LIKE',"$search%")
                ->get();

        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

```
    ajax: {
            url: "/dxcodes",
            dataType: "json",
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
              return {
                q: $.trim(params.term)
              };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
              return {
                results: data
              };
            },
            cache: true
        }
```

my json response is: [] (after running tests, I found my $request->q is treated as empty) however, if I remove the if(empty), I get my response. I don't understand it... again, please remember, all this works perfectly on my local machine. I have other ajax calls in my app on the production server and they work fine, it's just this one call.

The fix for this issue was the nginx web server config file for this site was not set correctly. Nginx doesn't use .htaccess files. The ? was missing after index.php

```
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string; (BAD)
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; (GOOD)
```

Comment: Can you provide the version of Laravel your project is using?

Comment: So, there are no errors in console, Laravel logs?

Comment: @FrancinaldoAlmeida I've updated my question, it's version 5.8.11

Comment: @Tarasovych Correct, reason why is when the method is triggered, its going to the if(empty) clause, so there won't be an error. Which is the part that is not making sense. why is it going into the if(empty) statement, because if I remove the empty statement, the var $request->q is set.

Comment: Please try to log the request `\Log::debug($request->all());` and let us know the result.

Comment: @whyguy It's showing as blank... hmmmm
[2019-04-12 09:16:47] local.DEBUG: array (
)

Comment: Try to open the url from your browser with `q` set to something

Comment: Yeah, that's what I just did, if I do the exact same thing on my local machine, I get the output of
[2019-04-12 09:18:52] local.DEBUG: array (
  'term' => 'a',
  '_type' => 'query',
  'q' => 'a',
)  
which is what is expected, so any thoughts as to why my request is null on my server?

Comment: interesting enough, if I use dd($request->fullUrl()); on my server, it returns the full URL without the query, it's as if for some reason something is removing the query from the request.

Comment: Found the issue, sigh... my server is running nginx, so it's not using the .htaccess file, I will need to change the nginx config to act as .htacsess. Thanks for your help!